# Should a one page app contain only buttons?

Tags: html, button, anchor, semantics

I'm writing a one page store application and I've set up the menu as usual with ordinary anchor tags because it's been designed as such. Yet, while I will implement browser history, I will also preventDefault and treat them like buttons just opening a new view.

Should the menu be redesigned to show buttons instead anchor tags. It's familiarity vs. actual function (and semantic correctness, I believe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's consult [the spec.](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

What is an `<a>` element?

> If the a element has an href attribute, then it represents a hyperlink (a hypertext anchor) labeled by its contents.
>
> If the a element has no href attribute, then the element represents a placeholder for where a link might otherwise have been placed, if it had been relevant, consisting of just the element's contents.

What about a `<button>` element?

> The button element represents a button labeled by its contents.

#### So what does this mean?

If you're representing an actual link in your navigation (even if it's using the HTML5 History API), I say use an `<a>` element. If you're not, using a `<button>` might be better.

For navigation, I'd probably use an `a` tag.

#### Semantic HTML is not the only issue here

Another issue is SEO, crawlers like GoogleBot will have a much easier time figuring out they should follow `a` links than `button`s.